# Can you get a closed-form for $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_2^x-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt$ and evaluate its limit as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I know how deduce for $x>1$ that  $$-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{x^{2n+2}},$$
and from a online tool that
$$\int -\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx =-x\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\log(1-x)-\log(1+x)+\text{constant}.$$

> **Question 1.** Can you prove this fact, it is a/previous closed form for $$\int_2^x-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt?$$

I don't know how evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_2^x-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt.$$

When I type the integral or previous closed form for the integral, or the limit for the symbolic integral I obtain from the online resource one time $\infty$ and other time $i\pi$. By assumption of previous closed form I compute $\lim_{x\to\infty}-x\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=0$, when I assume convergence in previous series expansion, and I deduce that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left({\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)$ doesn't exists. Perhaps I need show a kind of convergence to combine with some integral theorem, is it?

I need refresh this computations.

> **Question 2.** Can you help me to know where were the mistakes? I say, can you compute previous $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_2^x-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt?$$

**Thanks in advance.** I need this facts, when I did this afternoon some computations using the **Hermite-Hadamard inequality** for this function, for wich I showed in my computations that is convex $x>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question hint**

$$\log\left(1- \frac{1}{t^2}\right) = \log\left(\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}\right) = \log(t^2 - 1) - \log(t^2) = \log(t^2-1) - 2\log(t)$$

Split the integral in the two parts, use log properties and integrate by part as you usually do when you have simple logarithms.

**Second question Hint**

By the result of the integration, you have:

$$\left[-x\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right) + \log(1-x) - \log(1+x)\right]\bigg|_2^{\infty} = \left[-x\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right) + \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\right]\bigg|_2^{+\infty}$$

You observe that since $x\to \infty$ you have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} -x\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \log(1-x) - \log(1+x) = \lim_{x\to \infty}\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) = i\pi$$

When $x\to 2$ you simply have $i\pi - \log\left(\frac{27}{16}\right)$

Then do the math.

**Explanation of the limit**

$$e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0 ~~~~~ \to ~~~~~ -1 = e^{i\pi}$$

Thence

$$\ln(-1) = \ln(e^{i\pi}) = i\pi$$

Comment: Very thanks much, now I am taking notes to study your answers.

Comment: @user243301 You're welcome! If you need some help, just comment here. I just gave you hints but I believe you can do it entirely now!

Comment: Very thanks much for your details, if I need more hints I call you. Thanks

Comment: I will try your hints, very thanks much for the trick about $\lim_{x\to2}$ that removes $i\pi$ and by the explanation of the limit.

Comment: When I do computations combining your hints with $\int\log udu=u\log u-u$, I split $-\int\log(1-1/t^2)$, and I've computed $\int\log(t-1)dt$, $\int\log(t+1)dt$ and $\int\log(t^2)dt$ to get the closed form, as you said. But in the second question, I understand all, except the fact that $\lim_{x\to 2}\log\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\log(-\frac{1}{3})$, thus (and I've tried combine with your trick with **Euler's identity**) still I have complex numbers in my computations, and I don't know how solve the situation. Thanks.

Comment: @user243301 When you try to compute the limit for $x\to 2$, just use the properties of logarithm to write:

$$-x\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right) + \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) = -\log\left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\right)  + \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$$

In which you used simply the fact that $a\log(b) = \log(b^a)$. Now if you use the property $\log(X) - \log(Y) = \log(X/Y)$ you get

$$\log\left(\frac{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x}\right)$$

Comment: Now if you substitute $x = 2$ you will get

$$\log\left(-\frac{16}{27}\right)$$

Which can be seen as 

$$\log\left(-1\cdot \frac{16}{27}\right)$$

Using the property $\log(a\cdot b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ you get:


$$\log(-1) +\log(16/27)$$

Now $\log(-1) = i\pi$ and you can see (just because) $\log(16/27) = -\log(27/16)$ and you will have the result

$$i\pi - \log(27/16)$$

Comment: Now I believe that understand your answer, now I do your computations as you say, very thanks much.